# How to remove arrows in the second-level menu items in weebly?

Tags: html, css, submenu

the website i am talking about is : http://www.events.elenifrantzi.com/
there are two problems with the second level submenu as you can see.
the first is the arrow (i cannot get rid of it) 
the second is the distance between first level submenu and second.
i cannot find anything that it change these two things....

the css for the menu is:

/* side-nav
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

```
#avmenu {
clear: left;
float: left;
width: 70px;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
font-size: 17px;
}

#avmenu ul {
list-style: none;
width: 70px;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

#avmenu li {
list-style: none;
}

#avmenu li a {
font-weight: 300;
line-height: 1;
text-decoration: none;
color: #7b7b7b;
font-family: "Dosis", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 16px;
display: block;
padding: 11px 5px 11px 0;
border-bottom: 1px solid #2a2a2a;
}



#avmenu li#active a,
#avmenu a:hover {
color: #b1b1b1;
background: #1e1e1e;
}
```

/* Navigation Drop-Down Menu Customization
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

```
#wsite-menus .wsite-menu {
position: relative;
top: 0;
}

#wsite-menus .wsite-menu li a {
padding: 6px 5px 7px -25px;
width: 90px;
background: none;
border: none;
text-decoration: none;
font-family: "Dosis", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 14px;
display: block;
font-weight: 300;
color: #7b7b7b;
}

#wsite-menus .wsite-menu li a:hover {
color: #b1b1b1;
background: none;
}
```

and the html:

```
<div id="main-wrap">
<div id="main">
<div id="avmenu">{menu}</div>
<div id="content">{content}
<div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

please help!!!
and thank you in advance

Comment: Have you tried using the developer toolbar? You should be able to see what css causes these things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for spacing you can try this

`.wsite-menu-wrap ul li div.wsite-menu-wrap {
    left: 111px !important;
}`

;)

Comment: thank you very much! i can now change the distance between them.

Answer (score 0):

Change submenu width from 200px to 100px (most numbers are hardcoded anyway, so I assume you don't worry about long menu entries)

```
#weebly-menus .weebly-menu li, #wsite-menus .wsite-menu li {
    ...
    width: 100px;
}
```

Remove `wsite-menu-arrow` from HTML, or at least hide it

```
#wsite-menus .wsite-menu-arrow {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: thank you for the solution about the arrows. it worked!!

Comment: but the width cannot change...maybe i cannot understand exactly what you advise me to do. the width as you can see in the code is either 70 or 90 px